# Is there a way of moving one node and for all the children nodes to move with it ? D3?

Tags: d3.js

Basically what the question asks.

I have a force layout graph and use dragstart, dragmove and dragend. When I move one node, the force layout stops and only the node I select moves.

I am wondering if anyone can point me in the right way so when I move this node, if it has children, all the children move with it.

Or have any links to examples I may be able to work from ?

Also, I have a way of selecting nodes and they become highlighted and also get added to an array. Is there a way that I can highlight a few of these nodes and move/drag them all at once ?